# c's fprintf writes garbage to the end of file

Tags: xml, printf, garbage

I am working on some legacy C program. It is some 20 years old version of C, and some old **Unix OS** (I am not familiar with the exact versions). Anyway, I need to write an xml file, so I wrote the program here at my **Ubuntu** machine, and when I started it there on that old system, I got some garbage at the end of my xml , which looks like a rectangle with something like:

```
0 0 
1 A
```

The problem is that I cannot reproduce it here at Ubuntu, probably the newer C can handle the case. My guess is that the problem is related to string terminating character `\0`. I 'm just not sure where is it happening, so I would like to have as much as possible ideas tomorrow, when I arrive there to fix it.
Finally, my question is, do you think it is possible that the problem is newline `\n`, at the last `fprintf`? 
Or, may the following be a problem:

```
char name[50]; //this is read from file at some point
char first[50];
char last[50];
strcpy(first,strtok(name, " "));
strcpy(last,strtok(NULL, " "));
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
strncpy(first,strtok(name, " "),50);
strncpy(last,strtok(NULL, " "),50);
```

this will take care of the `\0` if for some reason `name` does not contain `\0`
in its 50 characters.

Generally it is a better tactic to use `strncpy` than `strcpy`.

In normal execution their
behave the same way. The difference is that during an overflow situation `strncpy` will protect you other variables and terminate the string correctly with a `\0` while `strcpy` will fail to do so resulting in memory overflow and non-terminating strings.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will try and let you know what happened.